# Parse yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss using DateFormatter in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I would like to parse `Year:Month:Day:Hour:Minute:Second` (e.g. `2017:01:01:23:59:59`) in Swift. I am using the following `dateFormat`: `yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss` though the date formatter returns nil when given a string:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.date(from: "2017:01:01:23:59:59") // nil
```

[NSDateFormatter.com](https://www.nsdateformatter.com/) says there is something invalid in either my date or format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hh should be HH in answer. dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your format is incorrect. It should be `yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss` instead. `HH` for hours.